# How can I round the values displayed in a matplotlib pie chart?

Tags: python, matplotlib, charts

The example code for a pie chart is given [here](http://matplotlib.org/1.2.1/examples/pylab_examples/pie_demo.html):

```
figure(1, figsize=(6,6))
ax = axes([0.1, 0.1, 0.8, 0.8])    
labels = 'Frogs', 'Hogs', 'Dogs', 'Logs'
fracs = [15, 30, 45, 10]
explode=(0, 0.05, 0, 0)

pie(fracs, explode=explode, labels=labels,
                autopct='%1.1f%%', shadow=True, startangle=90)

title('Raining Hogs and Dogs', bbox={'facecolor':'0.8', 'pad':5})

show()
```

The output looks like this:

[image: Pie Chart Demo]

I'd like it to just say 15%, 10%, etc, without the unnecessary decimal place at the end. How can I go about doing that?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Just change the autopct='%**1.0**f%%' from autopct='%**1.1**f%%'

```
"""
Make a pie chart - see
http://matplotlib.sf.net/matplotlib.pylab.html#-pie for the docstring.

This example shows a basic pie chart with labels optional features,
like autolabeling the percentage, offsetting a slice with "explode",
adding a shadow, and changing the starting angle.

"""
from pylab import *

# make a square figure and axes
figure(1, figsize=(6,6))
ax = axes([0.1, 0.1, 0.8, 0.8])

# The slices will be ordered and plotted counter-clockwise.
labels = 'Frogs', 'Hogs', 'Dogs', 'Logs'
fracs = [15, 30, 45, 10]
explode=(0, 0.05, 0, 0)

pie(fracs, explode=explode, labels=labels,
                autopct='%1.0f%%', shadow=True, startangle=90)
                # The default startangle is 0, which would start
                # the Frogs slice on the x-axis.  With startangle=90,
                # everything is rotated counter-clockwise by 90 degrees,
                # so the plotting starts on the positive y-axis.

title('Raining Hogs and Dogs', bbox={'facecolor':'0.8', 'pad':5})

show()
```